# Any data type not working in data class kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, data-class

I just started to learn kotlin.

This is my data class.

```
data class UserModel(

    @SerializedName("Id")
    val id: Int = 0,

    @SerializedName("myKey")
    val myKey: Boolean? = false
    //var myKey: Any?
```

While I use simple as `val myKey: Boolean? = false` then my app is working and able to run . But when i use `var myKey: Any?` and run the app it give me compilation error. I have checked by commenting the code for every line. I found the issue occurs because of this `var myKey: Any?`

So kindly, if any one knows about this. Advanced help would be appreciated !

Comment: You sure it's not just because you have a duplicate `myKey` property name?

Comment: Yes Sir I m sure.. I have applied different variable name too

Comment: When you are assinging it to `false` as **Default** why do u need null safety ?

Comment: Compiles fine for me. Are you getting a compilation error or a runtime error?

Comment: Compile time Sir. _Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Compilation error. See log for more details...   org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
 at_

Comment: And have you? Checked the log for more details?

Comment: Sir _var isAllow: Any? = ""_ is this right?

Comment: Can you post your full data class please?

Answer (score -1):

try from

```
@SerializedName("myKey")
val myKey: Boolean? = false
```

into

```
@SerializedName("myKey")
val myKey: any? = false
```

example:

```
data class UserModel(

    @SerializedName("Id")
    val id: Int = 0,


    @SerializedName("myKey")
    val myKey: any? = false

)
```

make sure to do some type check and cast when accessing the data class such as

```
val userModel = UserModel()
when(userModel.myKey){
    is Boolean -> {
        // do stuff when myKey type of Boolean
        if(userModel.myKey) println("key is false")
        else println("key is true")
    }
    is String -> {
        // do stuff when myKey type of String
        println(userModel.myKey)
    }
}
```